# flag in test causes other tests to fail to run

Tags: testing, go

I have a test file that I want to only run when a bit flag is set. I followed the simple example from [golang's testing docs](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#hdr-Main):

```
package mypkg

var myFlagSet = flag.Bool("myflag", false, "")
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    flag.Parse()
    if *myFlagSet {
        os.Exit(m.Run())
    }
}
```

if I run `go test ./mypkg -myflag` it runs as expected. However, when I run `go test ./... -myflag`, all other package tests fail:

```
flag provided but not defined: -myflag
```

I want to be able to run all tests and not have to worry about parsing this flag in every test file. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing?

Comment: Have you perhaps overlooked the built-in [-short flag](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/#Short)?

Comment: yes, I've read about the `-short` flag, which is nice. However, I want my particular tests to only be run in an opt-in basis instead of an opt-out basis. Since the `-short` flag is off by default, I'd be checking if it's set and it doesn't make sense in my case to categorize these tests as "short" tests (it's more of an integration or e2e scenario)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you run `test ./...` it runs tests for each package *as a separate executable*, with the same parameters. So if you want to pass a flag to every package, every package has to accept it. You might want to use an env var instead, which can be read by packages that use it and ignored by those that don't.

Comment: bummer. This makes adding flags to tests seem really fragile. I'll go the env var route. Thanks!