# How to use custom flag in tests (with `testify/suite`)

Tags: go, testify, go-testing, go-flag

I want to add custom flags for my Go tests that use testify/suite. It looks like from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27342973/custom-command-line-flags-in-gos-unit-teststhat) that it can only be in `TestMain()` (`init()` if it is before Go 1.13). However, with the testify/suite pacakge, `TestMain()` is not quite an option. I have tried declaring the flags in `SeupSuite()` and `TestMyTestSuite()` which seems to be a corresponding `TestMain()` but both returned the error `flag provided but not defined: -mycustomflag`. Below is the sample code. Any suggestion will be appreciated!

my_test.go:

```
package main

import (
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/stretchr/testify/suite"
    "testing"
)

type MyTestSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
}

func (suite *MyTestSuite) SetupSuite() {
    flagBoolPtr := flag.Bool("mycustomflag", false, "this is a bool flag")
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Printf("my flag is set to: %t", *flagBoolPtr)
}

func TestMyTestSuite(t *testing.T) {
    // flagBoolPtr := flag.Bool("mycustomflag", false, "this is a bool flag")
    // flag.Parse()
    // fmt.Printf("my flag is set to: %t", *flagBoolPtr)
    suite.Run(t, new(MyTestSuite))
}

func (suite *MyTestSuite) TestBuildClosure() {
    fmt.Println("my test")
}
```

This is the command I used:

```
go test my_test.go -mycustomflag
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The test binary generated by `go test` is already using the `flag` package internally and calls `flag.Parse()` during normal operation.
Define the flag variable as global (✳️) so they are known before running `flag.Parse()`.

```
type MyTestSuite struct {
    suite.Suite
}

// ✳️
var flagBoolPtr = flag.Bool("mycustomflag", false, "this is a bool flag")

func (suite *MyTestSuite) SetupSuite() {
    fmt.Printf("my flag in SetupSuite: %t\n", *flagBoolPtr)
}

func TestMyTestSuite(t *testing.T) {
    fmt.Printf("my flag in test: %t\n", *flagBoolPtr)
    suite.Run(t, new(MyTestSuite))
}

func (suite *MyTestSuite) TestBuildClosure() {
    fmt.Println("my test")
}
```

```
go test -v my_test.go -mycustomflag

=== RUN   TestMyTestSuite
my flag in test: true
my flag in SetupSuite: true
=== RUN   TestMyTestSuite/TestBuildClosure
my test
--- PASS: TestMyTestSuite (0.00s)
    --- PASS: TestMyTestSuite/TestBuildClosure (0.00s)
PASS
```

> Although what if I have multiple testsuites aka multiple files in the same package? And I want to use this flag for all testsuites? Since we can define the variable and the flag only once, how can I make sure this declaration in this specific testsuite gets executed first?

To `run` test separately in the package, create a file for the  `package` contains only with required `flag` (✳️) and compile single `test` with file, which contains `flags`

```
.
├── my_test.go
├── other_my_test.go
└── flag_test.go // ✳️
```

`flag_test.go`

```
package any

import "flag"

var flagBoolPtr = flag.Bool("mycustomflag", false, "this is a bool flag")
```

```
go test -v flag_test.go my_test.go -mycustomflag
```

also you can `run` all tests with required `flag`

```
 go test -v ./... -mycustomflag
```

Comment: Appreciate the answer! That does seem to work. Although what if I have multiple testsuites aka multiple files in the same package? And I want to use this flag for all testsuites? Since we can define the variable and the flag only once, how can I make sure this declaration in this specific testsuite gets executed first?

Comment: Love the solution. Looks super clean. Thank you so much!